# Unable to render an angularjs template inside a popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get a popover show some html content (it could be angularjs compiled content) and when I click on my "View" link, I do not see my custom directive getting processed and showing correctly (all other content is rendering okay including one that has an ng-repeat inside it suggesting that angularjs saw my angular content right)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Jy8Qlp1rsghwj4NNF2Dn?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="ChordCtrl">
    <chord-layout chord-matrix="{{matrix}}">
       <div id="chordLayoutHolder"></div>
    </chord-layout> 
</div>
```

There is a lot going on in this plunkr but the bottom line is when I click on any of the "View" inside the table, I expect dynamic contents of report1.html to show up in my tooltip - Clearly all the other contents show up but it somehow failed to do my complex chord layout rendering - The chord layout diagram rendering is tested independently in another plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/q5DDdKHs11OuW6SfLtTG?p=preview

Any help in determining why my chord layout chart is not rendering would be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having issues because you're using `id` for your chordLayoutHolder. To be honest, I'm not sure why this is an issue. Perhaps Angular pre-compiles the template and clones it, such that the `id` is no longer unique. I would be curious to know.

In any case, remove `<div id="chordLayoutHolder"></div>` and just append to the directive element:

```
<chord-layout chord-matrix="{{matrix}}">
</chord-layout>
```

Then, in your directive, change the following lines (that refer to chordLayoutHolder):

```
$("#chordLayoutHolder").empty();
var svg = d3.select("#chordLayoutHolder")
...
```

to:

```
element.empty();
var domElement = angular.element(element)[0];
var svg = d3.select(domElement)
...
```

to append to the element itself, rather than another placeholder.

Then it would work. Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gMFDCTEISWZy1FGKtSU7).

Comment: Thank you very much. While writing directives, I will keep this in mind that I can append any content to the "element" itself.